# PyQt GUI won't show when ran as root

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a python app that I use as a manager for a deamon of mine. It works perfectly, but I started changing the deamon, and so I had to also make some changes on my python manager, mostly to write and read some files, and for that I need root permission, but when a run it as root, all of the GUI, that is accessible by a QSystemTrayIcon, just won't show. Gksudo won't work, and sudo returns this error:

> "sni-qt/2708" WARN  13:48:48.924 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE"

Comment: Why you not try to run as a nomal user but at some point perform a `setuid`?

Comment: Try creating a simple PyQt test app with GUI and see if you can run it as root.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, I already tried `setuid`, but I get "OSError: [Error 1] Operation not permitted", even though I give all the permissions to the script, even u+s

Comment: @hyde, I tried another PyQt app I have and it worked, it was a little bit different, but I guess it has something to do with the users themes. I think the problem is with the QSystemTrayIcon, or the path to the image I use as the icon, beacause when I run it with gksudo I get no errors, but the icon won't show, even though I'm uisng it's real path.